# Is there a way to check request.user against ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

I have a small problem and wondering if someone can help me out.  I'm trying to do a check to see if the request.user is one of the user's in the ManyToMany relationship table.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Example:

I want to check if the user is following the business page, and if they are, give them the ability to unfollow it and vice versa.

I have:

```
followers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="Followers", null=True, blank=True)
```

Just wondering if theres a way to check the request.user.id against the followers table for that specific id.

Thanks everyone.

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "djangoic" way to do it:

```
if page.followers.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
   do_something()
```

The more "pythonic" way, which is **not recommended** because it is very inefficient db wise:

```
if request_user in page.followers.all():
   do_something()
```

(This later one loads all users data into python, while the first one uses a db query)

Answer (score 0):

you should be easily able to check

```
try:
    this_page = BusinessPages.objects.get(slug=slug)
except BusinessPage.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404

if request.user in this_page.followers.all():
    ...
```

Comment: This seems like a great place to use `get_object_or_404`:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404

Comment: @Jack M. It is certainly. I just wanted to show explicitly that an exception could be raised when querying a BusinessPage that isn't there